# Switch from 5" HVAC Air Filter to 4" Air Filter?

Tags: hvac

Hi: I have 2 HVAC systems that use 20" x 24" x 5" air filters that are quite expensive to replace @ $60 each every 9 months.

Would switching to 4" filters be ok assuming I change them slightly more often? They would save me some dough.

Thanks!!

Comment: I would continue to use the filter that the system is designed for.

Comment: your air filter is 5" thick?